# How to specify different command timeouts in the same accessor in BLToolkit?

Tags: .net, bltoolkit

Let's consider I have `FruitAccessor` with two methods: `GetBananas` and `GetApples`.

```
public abstract class FruitAccessor : DataAccessor
{
    [SprocName("GetAllBananas")]
    public abstract IEnumerable<Banan> GetBananas([ParamName("@MaxCount")] int count);

    public abstract IEnumerable<Apple> GetApples();
}
```

The default command timeout for both methods is 30 seconds. It's fine for `GetBananas`, but not enough for `GetApples`, so I want to increase it to 1 minute.

I can override `OnInitCommand` in `DbManager` but it will affect both methods.

It would be great to drop something like `[CommandTimeout(60 * 60)]` attribute on `GetApples` method, but unfortunately there is no such attribute.

So the question is how to achieve different timeouts for methods in the same `DataAccessor`?

Answer (score 0):

You can request this feature here - https://github.com/igor-tkachev/bltoolkit/issues